# Login page using Angular2

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular2. I have a separate login page, I cannot use it as a component since the styling is very different from the the rest of the application. I am able to use the login page as a component, but I need to create a separate page so that I can redirect to my main application once the user is logged in.

Login page like below:

```
<body class="login">
</body>
```

The rest of the page is like:

```
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: made a small edit to show the type of differences in both the htm files.

Comment: `the styling is very different from the the rest of the application` that's why angular2 have `styles` attribute in `component` decorator.

Comment: Yes @choz, They are essentially two different pages with different html.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a login component and completely isolate its styles. That is to say, it wouldn't interfere in other page's styling.

Take a look at the [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation) property.

Here is another link: [View Encapsulation in Angular2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)

In this case, your body in `index.html` would look like the same for all the pages. What you would be styling is the component itself

```
<body>
...
</body>


<body>
   <login><!-- this is the where styling should start from --!>
     ...
   </login>
</body>
```

And your component:

```
@Component({
  selector:      'login',
  pipes:         [ ],
  providers:     [ ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  styles:        [ 
    ".login { 
      ...
    "
  ],
  template: "<div class='login'...> </div>"
```